# PHP: Rewrite rule with variable query string

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am in the middle of changing our site URL structure from this `site.com/?team=john-doe` to `site.com/attorney/john-doe`. I have the typical WordPress Htaccess rewrite rules in the htaccess file but what I'm having trouble is we have multiple attorneys that have the `?team=`followed by the name. I am trying to do one rule to redirect all with the name being a variable - if that makes sense.

```
site.com/?team=jane-doe
site.com/?team=nic-cage
```

Below I commented out a method but when I tried it I got 500 Internal Server error:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?team=([x]*)$
#RewriteRule ^(.*) site.com/attorneys/$1 [R=302,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I also applied this regex:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?team=(.*)$ site.com/attorneys/$1
```

Regex is pretty confusing, sorry if I'm not making any sense. I can try and clarify if needed.

Answer (score 1):

RedirectMatch only works for **uris** .you can't access querystring using this directive. You can use the following RewriteRule , add this before your wordpress rules :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^team=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/attorneys/%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks - I will give this a shot after business hours. Will report back!

Answer (score 0):

I am not so much sure but can you try this
  
`RewriteRule ^/?team=(.*)$ http://Yoursitename/attorneys/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Thanks - I will give this a shot after business hours. Will report back!

Comment: Hi @Ankit Prajapati the final solution was `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^team=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.andrewsmyers.com/attorneys/%1? [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but I think the leading question mark `?` in

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?team=([x]*)$
```

is the reason for the `500` server error, because `?` is a special character.

`?` means the preceding element is optional, but since there is no preceding element in `^?team=`, this is an error. If you want to match a literal question mark, you must escape it with a backslash `\?`.

Although, in this case (`QUERY_STRING`), this is not necessary, because `QUERY_STRING` does not contain the leading question mark, just the query string itself. This means checking for `team=(.*)` would be sufficient

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^team=(.*)$
```

---

There are additional issues with the rule

- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$` will match only the home page, nothing else
- `RewriteRule ^(.*) site.com/attorneys/$1 [R=302,L]` will not redirect to `site.com`, because it is missing `http://`
- and finally, the back-reference for matches in `RewriteCond` is `%1` instead of `$1`

Comment: Thanks for your descriptive response. So I updated my rules to what you have suggested and it's currently appending `?team=john-doe` to the new destination URL. Ex., `http://www.example.com/attorneys/?team=john-doe`

Comment: Yes, I missed that. My answer just explains, why you get a 500 error. But @starkeen already solved this problem with his answer by adding a question mark to the target. This prevents, that the previous query string is added to the new target.